# Why do non-real solutions of a polynom occur pairwise complex-conjugated?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So if I have a polynom with real coefficients and the solution $x+iy$, why is $x-iy$ always a solution too?

Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers, with $w^{\ast}$ = complex-conjugated of $w$, then
$$(z-w)(z-w^{\ast}) = z^2 -2z\mathrm{Re}(w) + |w|^2$$
All coefficients are real, but how do I prove the other direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to get non-real roots to a real polynomial, you extend the reals by adding a formal symbol, which is normally called 'i', but I will call 'h' just to be different, with the constraint that h^2=-1. So then you get some root involving h.

But now we say, "really" the root of -1 is 'i', so setting i=h gives the root we just found. But then we ask, what if 'i' is really -h? Could there be any difference? Since (-h)^2 is also -1 by elementary algebra, there is no way to say that h is "really" i or -i. But if a non-real value were a root without its complex conjugate being a root, then there would be a contradiction, because we would have to have a way of saying which of i and -i is "really" h.

This is an extremely informal argument, but I think the crux of the matter is that i is only defined in this formal manner.

Answer (score 9):

If $f$ is the polynomial and $z$ is a root, then $f(z)=0$. But $f(\bar z)=\overline{f(z)}=\bar 0=0$, so $\bar z$ is also a root.

EDIT: (Why is $f(\bar z)=\overline{f(z)}$)
First, note that for every pair of complex numbers $w,z$ you have:

- $\bar z\bar w=\overline{zw}$
- $\bar z+\bar w=\overline{z+w}$

Now put $f(X)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_jX^j$. Then,
$$f(\bar z)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j\bar z^j=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j\overline{z^j}\stackrel*=\sum_{j=0}^n \overline{a_jz^j}=\overline{\sum_{j=0}^na_jz^j}=\overline{f(z)}$$

(*) Here is essential that $a_j\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: why is $f(\bar z)=\overline{f(z)}$ ?

Comment: @Christian: Because the coefficients of $f$ are real. And complex conjugates commutes with powers of $z$, i.e. $(\overline{z})^{n} = \overline{z^{n}}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This follows from $\overline{zw}=\overline{z}\cdot \overline{w}$.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, we show that if a complex number is a root of a polynomial equation, then its complex conjugate is also root of the polynomial equation. Consider
$$f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i} x^{i} = 0,$$
in which $a_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose some complex number $\xi$ is a root of $f(x) = 0$; that is,
$$f(\xi) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i} \xi^{i} = 0.$$
Now, let $\xi^{\ast}$ be the complex conjugate of $\xi$. By the [properties of complex conjugation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate#Properties),
$$
    f(\xi^{\ast}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i} (\xi^{\ast})^{i}
    = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i} (\xi^{i})^{\ast}
    = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (a_{i} \xi^{i})^{\ast}
    = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i} \xi^{i}\right)^{\ast}.
$$
Since
$$\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i} \xi^{i}\right)^{\ast}  = 0^{\ast},$$
it follows that
$$
    f(\xi^{\ast}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i} (\xi^{\ast})^{i} = 0^{\ast} = 0,
$$
as required.

Since complex conjugate roots come in conjugate pairs, there are even number of them. It follows from this and the [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) that a polynomial of even degree has either even number of real roots or even number of complex conjugate roots, or both, whereas a polynomial of odd degree always has an odd number of real roots, the rest of them being complex conjugate pairs.

Comment: nice answer, thank you!